# RAILS - deleted entry still appears on the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index page like ths :

```
def index
    @admin_albums = Admin::Album.unscoped

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @admin_albums }
    end
  end
```

I also have a destroy action :

```
def destroy
    @admin_album = Admin::Album.unscoped.find(params[:id])


    @admin_album.destroy



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_albums_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

And an index view :

```
<% @admin_albums.each do |admin_album| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= admin_album.admin_style.nom %></td>
    <td><%= admin_album.titre %></td>
    <td><%= admin_album.artiste %></td>
    <td><%= truncate(admin_album.critiques, :length => 255).html_safe %></td>
    <td><%= oui_non(admin_album.public) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Voir', admin_album %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Modifier', edit_admin_album_path(admin_album) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Supprimer', admin_album, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Êtes-vous sûr ?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem is : when I click on "Supprimer", to delete an entry, I'm redirected to the index page, and the entry still appears on the page. However it is well deleted in the database !
How is it possible ?

If I refresh the page, the entry is stil there ! I have to wait few minutes before the entry disappears on the index page.

In the logs, it seems that the request "Admin::Album.unscoped.all" is ignored, you can see it :

```
Started GET "/admin/albums" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-26 20:04:09 +0200
Processing by Admin::AlbumsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mAdmin::Couleurmenu Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `admin_couleurmenus`.* FROM `admin_couleurmenus` ORDER BY `admin_couleurmenus`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered admin/albums/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 54.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

EDIT : Destroy action in the log :

```
Started DELETE "/admin/albums/33" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-26 20:04:09 +0200
Processing by Admin::AlbumsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"b79G4x4m0X56OaRFskKkpLet67IzJfpGAPSsbK7U058=", "id"=>"33"}
  [1m[35mAdmin::Couleurmenu Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `admin_couleurmenus`.* FROM `admin_couleurmenus` ORDER BY `admin_couleurmenus`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mAdmin::Album Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `admin_albums`.* FROM `admin_albums` WHERE `admin_albums`.`id` = 33 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
[paperclip] Scheduling attachments for deletion.
  [1m[36mSQL (13.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM `admin_albums` WHERE `admin_albums`.`id` = 33[0m
[paperclip] Deleting attachments.
[paperclip] deleting C:/Ruby/ldp/public/system/admin/albums/pochettes/000/000/033/original/clap032_1440-1.jpg
[paperclip] deleting C:/Ruby/ldp/public/system/admin/albums/pochettes/000/000/033/medium/clap032_1440-1.jpg
[paperclip] deleting C:/Ruby/ldp/public/system/admin/albums/pochettes/000/000/033/thumb/clap032_1440-1.jpg
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/albums
Completed 302 Found in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)
```

Where is the problem ? Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Add the section of your log file that shows the destroy action being called.

Comment: Maybe your browser is caching page? Are you using memcached or something similar?

Comment: No i'm not using memcached, and the problem exists on multiple browsers.

Comment: You're not using a different database than the one you thought you were, are you?

Comment: No, it's impossible. And as I said, afer few minutes, the entry disappears like it should on the index page.

Comment: If you query for it in Rails console, is it showing up there as well?

Comment: @Beerlington yes it is.